# PowerShell: how to move a file from a remote computer to a network share

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to move a file from a network share to a remote computer (which I do not have admin rights on).  The source path on the network share is `\\share_computer\some_folder\file1.txt`.  The destination path to the file on the remote computer is `\\remote_computer\d$\another_folder`.

A simple `Move-Item $from $to` doesn't work.  I get a PermissionDenied message when I try to access the network share.  However, I have confirmed that I can access the shared file via something like

```
`$data = Get-Content "\\share_computer\some_folder\file1.txt"    

$var = $data[0]`
```

I then tried the following:

```
$src = "\\share_computer\some_folder\file1.txt"
$dest = "\\remote_computer\d$\another_folder"
$username = "my_username"
$password = "my_password"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)

$WebClient.DownloadFile($src, $dest)
```

PowerShell is throwing the following error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

I don't know why PowerShell is throwing this error.  Assuming the above is the correct technique to move the file, what do I need to do to correct it?  Or, if the above is the incorrect technique, what should I do?

Comment: `\\remote_computer\D:\another_folder` doesn't look right (the `D:` is not something I've seen used before). Does that work if you navigate to it using Windows Explorer?

Comment: RB right. You need to use $ sign rather then colon, to access to a remote driver.

Comment: You are correct.  I meant to type d$, not D:.  I have corrected the posting.

Comment: @user3100444 The WebClient is throwing an error because you are not talking to a web-server - it will never work. `Move-Item` is the correct approach - you just need to make sure that your permissions are correct. Get the copy working with Windows Explorer, then it should be trivial to write the corresponding `Move-Item` command as you will know the permissions and paths are both correct.

Comment: I tried $cred = Get-Credentials $from = "..." $to = "..." Move-Item $from $to -Credential $cred.  However, PowerShell is now throwing a new error: Move-Item: Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet.  The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet.  Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.  I know that I need to supply credentials.  But, my provider is not allowing the -Credential parameter.  Is there a work-around?